# Can't use Router inside of service with facebook-login plugin for Nativescript

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

The component I created which imports the FB login plugin (login part works fine):

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {FbloginService} from "../../services/fblogin.service";
var FacebookLoginHandler = require("nativescript-facebook-login");

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    providers: [FbloginService],
        templateUrl: "pages/login/login.html",
    })

export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private _fbloginService: FbloginService) {
    }

facebookLogin(){
        FacebookLoginHandler.init();
        //Register our callbacks
 FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback(this._fbloginService.successCallback, this._fbloginService.cancelCallback, this._fbloginService.failCallback);
//Start the login process
            FacebookLoginHandler.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"]);
            }
        }
```

You can see at the end in **FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback** Method. I register the fblogin service to be called on login success which is stored in the **fblogin.service.ts** which looks like

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";

@Injectable()
export class FbloginService {
    constructor(private _router: Router){
    }

successCallback(result) {
    var token;
    token = result.getAccessToken().getToken();
    console.log(token);
    this._router.navigate(['Home']);
};
```

The service runs on success but will only console log the result. When it comes to changing page using the Router service, it does not recognise it existing despite being injected with constructor, I assume it is because the service is not ran as a service when sent as parameter inside the registerCallback method.

This is the error returned

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {org.nativescript.map2/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException:  Calling js method onActivityResult
>   failed
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined File:
>   "/data/data/org.nativescript.map2/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-facebook-login/facebook-handler.js,
>   line: 45, column: 29
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'FbloginService.successCallback',
>   file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.map2/files/app/services/fblogin.service.js',
>   line: 13, column: 13  Frame:
>   function:'loginManager.registerCallback.com.facebook.FacebookCallback.onSuccess',
>   file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.map2/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-facebook-login/facebook-handler.js',
>   line: 35, column: 17  Frame: function:'act.onActivityResult',

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The code inside of the regsitercallback method inside the plugin, which is old nativescript I think

```
export function registerCallback(successCallback: any, cancelCallback: any, failCallback: any) {

if(_isInit){
  var act = _AndroidApplication.foregroundActivity || _AndroidApplication.startActivity;
  _act = act; 

  loginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new com.facebook.FacebookCallback({

    onSuccess: function(result) {
      successCallback(result);
    },
    onCancel: function() {
      cancelCallback();

    },
    onError: function(e) {
      failCallback(e);
    }

  }));

  //Overriding Activity onActivityResult method to send it to the callbackManager
  act.onActivityResult = (requestCode: number, resultCode: number, data: android.content.Intent) => {
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Would replacing the `this._router` inside successCallback with `_router` work?

Comment: I get a build error then app/services/fblogin.service.ts(14,9): error TS2663: Cannot find name '_router'. Did you mean the instance member 'this._router'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wrap your callback with the {N} runtime global, `zonedCallback`, or use `NgZone`. Third party plugins/services that callback into {N}+ng2 code need to be run through a zone. For example:

```
declare var zonedCallback: any;

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    providers: [FbloginService],
        templateUrl: "pages/login/login.html",
    })

export class LoginComponent {

constructor(private _fbloginService: FbloginService) {
}

facebookLogin(){
    FacebookLoginHandler.init();
    //Register our callbacks
    FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback(zonedCallback(this._fbloginService.successCallback), zonedCallback(this._fbloginService.cancelCallback), zonedCallback(this._fbloginService.failCallback));
```

Or another way:

```
import {Injectable, NgZone} from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";

@Injectable()
export class FbloginService {
    constructor(private _router: Router, private ngZone: NgZone){
    }

    successCallback(result) {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        var token;
        token = result.getAccessToken().getToken();
        console.log(token);
        this._router.navigate(['Home']);
      });
    }
}
```

Also see this: http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/videos/2016/06/13/zoned-callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback(this._fbloginService.successCallback, 
 this._fbloginService.cancelCallback, this._fbloginService.failCallback);
```

You could write a local callback function:

```
 FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback(successCB,           
  this._fbloginService.cancelCallback, this._fbloginService.failCallback);

function successCB()
{
    _fbloginService.successCallback();
}
```

Comment: If the callback accesses `this` then it should just be `FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback(() => this._fbloginService.successCallback(), 
() => this._fbloginService.cancelCallback(), () => this._fbloginService.failCallback());` where expected parameters should be inserted in `(...)` to get fowarded or alternatively ` FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback(this._fbloginService.successCallback.bind(this), 
 this._fbloginService.cancelCallback.bind(this), this._fbloginService.failCallback.bind(this));` I don't get how your answer would make difference but I might miss something.

Comment: to get it to compile from typescript I edited your suggesstion to `successCB(result){
        this._fbloginService.successCallback(result);
    }   ` which still through up the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_fbloginService' of undefined `I think the plugin is made for nativescript version 1 which might be causing the main issue

Comment: Actually my example above with `bind()` should be `bind(this.fbloginService)` instead of `bind(this)`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Your first suggestion works! sort of I used `FacebookLoginHandler.registerCallback((result) => this._fbloginService.successCallback(result),` now it recognises the router in the service (I tested by putting in a inccorect route var and it pops up with an error). However unusual behaviour now, it ignores the navigate method despite reading it first time, and when I click the login button a second time running the, it works

Comment: @AngJobs feel free to add my comments to your answer.

Comment: I guess the callbacks run outside Angulars zone. Inject `NgZone` and use `this.zone.run(() => { /* callback code here */ })` to force the execution back into Angulars zone.